# how do I add padding between checkbox and its content

Tags: c#, xamarin, checkbox, xamarin.winphone

In my Winphone 8.1 there is no padding between checkbox and its content they're so close while in visual studio xaml viewer I can see there is a space between them.

```
                  <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White">
                    <CheckBox Name="Chk1" Height="55" Content="blah blah1" Margin="5,0,0,0"></CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox Name="Chk2" Height="55" MinWidth="100" Content="Blah blah2"></CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>
```

I even tried adding minimum width but its of no use.. still no padding between the checkbox and its content.

Answer (score 1):

Use padding left then it should be fine

```
 <CheckBox Name="Chk1" Height="55" Padding="5,0,5,0" Content="blah blah1" Margin="5,0,0,0"></CheckBox>
 <CheckBox Name="Chk2" Height="55" Padding="5,0,5,0" MinWidth="100" Content="Blah blah2"></CheckBox>
```